Better way to shorten the loop
Is there any better way to shorten this code or remove the foreach loop?
var message = string.Empty;
                
if (myList.Any())
{
   foreach (var item in myList)
   {
       message += $"{item.HusbandFirstName} is married to {item .WifeFirstName}";
   }
}


I'd use a StringBuilder here and the if isn't really necessary but otherwise IMHO this is fine. What's your problem with foreach?

"but otherwise IMHO this is fine." - it's definitly not. It's probably the second worst way to do this. Just think about how many strings this will create.

@Fildor What is the worst way?

@Fildor that's why I said that I would use a StringBuilder. With fine I meant using foreach.

@SomeBody when you also += the components.

@BillTürstandswithUkraine Ok, in that case - then I just misread your statement.

The if any check doesn't really add much. Iterating an empty list is fine and it implicitly does the same thing.

Note, your code produces "John is married to JaneThomas is married to SaraLee is married to Lee..." - perhaps not the formatting you intended. Perhaps string.Join would suit you better, e.g. string.Join(", " myList.Select(item => $"{item.HusbandFirstName} is married to {item .WifeFirstName}"))

you can use LINQ with String.Concat
var message = string.Concat(myList.Select(item => $"{item.HusbandFirstName} is married to {item.WifeFirstName}"));

Use String.Join if you want a seperator
var message = string.Join(", ", myList.Select(item => $"{item.HusbandFirstName} is married to {item.WifeFirstName}"));


Just note that this is using ", " separator, while the OP has no separator.

true, update the post

You could also keep using Join with string.Join( "", ...). Don't know if your concat-approach would perform better, though.

var sb = new StringBuilder();
myList
.ForEach(l => sb.Append($"{l.HusbandFirstName} is married to {l.WifeFirstName}"));
var message = sb.ToString();

Depending on which version of .NET you are on you will make use of more or less performant overloads which will limit allocations and speed things up.

I don't think I'd swap a foreach out for .ForEach

@flackoverstow yeah, fair point. just wanted to make it shorter for OP. Just for completeness, what are the drawbacks of ForEach compared to foreach?

"Make it shorter" - 5 chars hardly seems worth it ;) and what you end up with is confusingly a List-only thing that looks like a LINQ thing that gets nasty as it gets longer. See also https://ericlippert.com/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/

Agreed. Thanks for the link. It encapsulates the negatives quite well.
